# how to handle null values comes through API in form of json in Spring?

Tags: json, spring

I got json from Api . It contain all value as a String. I converted in primitives all that according to required in my calculation. Anyone tell me how to handle when json return null value how to cast them according to java field.

```
{"student_answer":{"1" :"2","2":"3","3 ": "2"}}
```

where first values show answer no and second value.

```
Class Student_answer {

 private String   sQ1;
 private String   sQ2;
 private String   sQ3;
 private String   sQ4;

}
```

when all values comes from json it work fine, but when json have null value or "" value it show exception how to handle it?

Parsing code is here:

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/aakashv2/api";   
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);

    ReportComingValues value=null;
    try {
        value=objectMapper.readValue(new URL(uri),ReportComingValues.class);
    }catch(){}

public class ReportComingValues {

 private Id id;

    private Father_answer father_answer;

    private Mother_answer mother_answer;

    private Student_answer student_answer;

    private String student_rollno;

}
```

Comment: any other best way to handle this problem please suggest me.

Comment: Do You use Jackson for that? or some custom parser, or you assign that manually? Post that part of the code that does the unmarshalling.

Comment: code i show you above . want to handle null value if value are null atleast it return 0 .for mathmatical calculations.